# jquery, get index/eq value of element

Tags: jquery, indexing

I'm working with a page that has 44 different...

```
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
```

...elements on it. One of those also has the class "special". I'd like to know what it's index or eq() value is.

This is where I'm stuck -

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#container').find('.name').length; // 44 elems 
    $('#container').find('.name.special').length; // 1 elems 
    $('#container').find('.name.special').index(); // eq(0) 
});
```

How do I make it understand that I want .index() to tell me where .special is in context with the other 43 elems?

Just to be extra clear, here's a smaller version of what I have on a page:

```
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>

<a name="(various names)" class="name special"></a> <!-- what eq() is this? -->

<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
<a name="(various names)" class="name"></a>
```

What is the eq(number) or index value of .special?

Comment: If that's the actual code, `$('#container').find('.name.special').index();` should work perfectly fine, as long as the anchors actually are inside `#container` and are all siblings.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qqzcdoxj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $allNames = $('#container').find('.name'), // 44 elems
        $specialName = $('#container').find('.name.special'); // 1 elem

    console.log($allNames.index($specialName[0])); //get the index of special in all names
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/